# Avoiding SQL injection when saving user-agent using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-injection

I'm saving the browser user-agent of my users for stats purposes.

As you already know, user-agent can be modified. I would like to know if I should do anything to protect against SQL Injection.

I'm using Stored Procedures for inserting.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use parameters with stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx#paght000002_step2) or [use parameters with dynamic SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx#paght000002_step3).

Here's the example from MSDN:

```
  SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
       "SELECT CustomerID INTO #Temp1 FROM Customers " +
       "WHERE CustomerID > @custIDParm; SELECT CompanyName FROM Customers " +
       "WHERE Country = @countryParm and CustomerID IN " +
       "(SELECT CustomerID FROM #Temp1);",
       connection);
  SqlParameter custIDParm = dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
                                          "@custIDParm", SqlDbType.NChar, 5);
  custIDParm.Value = customerID.Text;

  SqlParameter countryParm = dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
                                      "@countryParm", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
  countryParm.Value = country.Text;

  connection.Open();
  DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
  dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to tell I'm already using SP with parameters

Comment: If you're following the pattern in the first link, you should be safe then. The parameter assembly code that builds the parameters into the query should properly encode the input to protect against SQL injection. (And that is the better solution.)

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that I'm using a max length of 512 bytes for the user-agent. Do you think that can be a problem?

Comment: Just make sure the database schema allows the length you expect, and check to make sure the given input is not over the length the schema allows.

Answer (score 0):

Use a prepared statement. Make sure you use a prepared statement for all SQL operations, even if the data comes out of the database.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean with prepared statement?

Comment: I think he means the same thing as a parametized query.